# Finding an expression for the constraint minimiser x

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, constraints

This is a question from a past exam paper.

**The Question:**
Let $A \in R^{m\times{n}}$ with $m > n$ have full column rank and $B \in R^{k\times{n}}$. Find an expression for the constraint minimiser $x \in R^{k}$ in terms of $A$, $B$, $b \in R^{m}$, $c \in R^k$ and the Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$ of minimise
$$\| b-Ax\|^2 : c^TBx=a $$

Then find the value of $\lambda$ which satisfies the constraint.

**What I've done so far:**
First of all, I inspected for small values of $m$,$n$,$k$. Setting $m=3$, $n=2$, $k=2$, we get:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11}       & a_{12} \\
    a_{21}       & a_{22} \\
    a_{31}       & a_{32}
\end{bmatrix}
B=\begin{bmatrix}
    b_{11}       & b_{12} \\
    b_{21}       & b_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
b=\begin{bmatrix}
    b_{1}\\
    b_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
c=\begin{bmatrix}
    c_{1}\\
    c_{2}
\end{bmatrix}$$
By Lagrange's Multipliers, we have:
$$L(x,\lambda)=\| b-Ax\|^2-\lambda(c^TBx-a)$$
Now we want to find some $x^*$, $\lambda^*$ such that we have $min\{L(x^*,\lambda^*)\}$. It then turns out that upon expanding $L(x,\lambda)$, we get:
$$(*)\implies L(x,\lambda)=(b_1-a_{11}x_1-a_{12}x_2)^2+(b_2-a_{21}x_1-a_{22}x_2)^2+(b_3-a_{31}x_1-a_{32}x_2)^2-\lambda(x_1(c_1b_{11}+c_2b_{21})+x_2(c_1b_{12}+c_2b_{22}))$$

Observing the above, we can bring $L(x,\lambda)$ to a finite minimum by minimising the square terms. Also, $A$ has full column rank, implying linear independence, meaning that the following combination exists:
$$(**)\implies \begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11}\\
    a_{21}\\
    a_{31}
\end{bmatrix}x_1+\begin{bmatrix}
    a_{12}\\
    a_{22}\\
    a_{32}
\end{bmatrix}x_2=0$$
That is, we can define our x to satisfy the above combination. With this in mind, we can substitute the system of equations from $(**)$ into each square term of $(*)$ which will result in the following
$$(***)\implies b_{1}^2+b_{2}^2+b_{3}^2-\lambda(x_1(c_1b_{11}+c_2b_{21})+x_2(c_1b_{12}+c_2b_{22}))$$

We now find the partial derivatives of $(*)$:
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_1}=2(b_{1}-a_{11}x_{1}-a_{12}x_{2})(-a_{11})+2(b_{2}-a_{21}x_{1}-a_{22}x_{2})(-a_{21})+2(b_{3}-a_{31}x_{1}-a_{32}x_{2})(-a_{31})-\lambda(c_1b_{11}+c_2b_{21})=0$$
And substituting $(**)$ we get:
$$(1)\implies -2a_{11}b_{1}-2a_{21}b_{2}-2a_{31}b_3-\lambda(c_1b_{11}+c_2b_{21})=0$$
And similarly when taking $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_2}$ and by $(**)$ we get:
$$(2)\implies -2a_{12}b_{1}-2a_{22}b_{2}-2a_{32}b_3-\lambda(c_1b_{12}+c_2b_{22})=0$$
Substituting $(1)$ & $(2)$ into $(***)$ yields:
$$L(x,\lambda)=b_{1}^2+b_{2}^2+b_{3}^2+2(x_1(2a_{11}b_{1}+2a_{21}b_{2}+2a_{31}b_3)+x_2(2a_{12}b_{1}+2a_{22}b_{2}+2a_{32}b_3))$$
thus giving me my constraint minimiser $x$. It turns out that for any $m$, $n$, $k$, we can write:
$$
L(x,\lambda)=\|b\|^2+2x^TAb \iff 
\begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11}\\
    \vdots \\
    a_{m1}
\end{bmatrix}x_1+\dots+
\begin{bmatrix}
    a_{1n}\\
    \vdots \\
    a_{mn}
\end{bmatrix}x_n$$

**My Problem:** The question asks to find the lagrange multiplier. The problem is that $\lambda$ is free in $L(x,\lambda)$, so something in my calculations must not make sense. I suspect this has got something to do when I take the partial derivatives. Help and solutions to this problem would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Why do want $x$ to solve $Ax=0$? The first error is step (**). The exercise is easier if you just keep $A$ and $b$ as-is and work with them as a general matrix and vector.